# When I try to remove element from HashSet which is not present, why it is not giving runtime error?

Tags: java, hashset

When I try to remove element from HashSet which is not present, why it does not give runtime error? [Please see following program on ideone](http://ideone.com/unpW6Z) with output.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HashSetTest2 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
       HashSet hs=new HashSet(); 
       hs.add("B");
       hs.add("A");
       hs.add("D");
       hs.add("E");
       System.out.println(hs);
       hs.add("F");           
       hs.remove("K");// Not present
    }    
}
```

//Run successfully
**output:** [D, E, F, A, B]

Comment: it returns boolean saying whether particular element is removed(present) or not(not present)

Comment: Why should it give error when not present?

Comment: Seems to me that this is the documented behaviour:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object). The return value indicates whether an element was actually removed as a result of the call.

Comment: @shazin, Thanks for replay. I got the answer. I was thinking that removing element which is not present should give runtime error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is how the interface was created: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

If you want to know if the set contained the removed object, just refer to the boolean value, method remove returns.

```
boolean existed=hs.remove("K");
if (!existed) {
  //You can throw your runtime exception here if you prefer it that way
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple way of telling the caller that some operation succeeded or not. One of those is throwing an exception when it failed, the other one is returning a boolean where `true` indicates "success" and `false` "failure".

[From the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object)):

> Returns true if this set contained the element (or equivalently, if this set changed as a result of the call).

Which can be paraphrased as "returns `false` if no element was found".

Answer (score 1):

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

It would just return you true or false based on availability of value in Hashset. You could further go ahead and have an if condition like:

```
if (!hs.remove("K")) {
   //now handle what you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it works like that :)
See the documentation right here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove(java.lang.Object) 
If you take a look at the remove():boolean method you can see that programmers wrote "Removes the specified element from this set if it is present." and also, it returns a boolean "true if the set contained the specified element" so... it returns true if AND ONLY IF the key is present.